# How to display 16-bit 4096 intensity image in Python openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have images encoded in grayscale 16-bit tiff format. They use a variant of 16-bit color depth where the max intensity is 4,096.

I believe the default max intensity in openCV is 65,536, so my image shows up as black using the following code.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("test.tif", -1)

cv2.imshow('tiff', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print(image)
```

[image]

I can use `vmin` and `vmax` in `matplotlib` to configure the color mapping:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

image = cv2.imread("test.tif", -1)
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=4096)
plt.show()
```

It shows the content of the image:

[image]

The reason why I want to stick with openCV is `matplotlib` doesn't support displaying 16-bit RGB images.

The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/df/d24/group__highgui__opengl.html#gaae7e90aa3415c68dba22a5ff2cefc25d) of `cv2.imshow` is not really helpful. Are there ways to display 16-bit 4096 intensity images in Python openCV?

The testing image `test.tif` can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ek31cxnmhbskdqm/test.tif?dl=0).

Comment: Maybe multiply your image by 16 for display, i.e. 65536/4096

Comment: I guess `cv2.equalizeHist` should do.

Comment: Or `cv2.normalize`

Comment: @jodis normalize yes, equalize no. Equalization is a non-linear mapping, you don’t want to do that in general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to use [`cv2.normalize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.normalize) to scale the image before displaying.

You can set the min/max of the image and it will scale the image appropriately (by moving the min of the image to `alpha` and max of the image to `beta`). Supposing your `img` is already a `uint16`:

```
img_scaled = cv2.normalize(img, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=65535, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

And then you can view as normal.

By default, `cv2.normalize()` will result in an image the same type as your input image, so if you want an unsigned 16-bit result, your input should be `uint16`.

---

Again, note that this linearly stretches your image range---if your image never actually hit 0 and say the lowest value was 100, after you normalize, that lowest value will be whatever you set `alpha` to. If you don't want that, as one of the comments suggests, you can simply multiply your image by 16, since it's currently only going up to 4095. With * 16, it will go up to 65535.