# cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH changes shape of a .tiff image

Tags: python, image, opencv, tiff, imread

I want to open an image using cv2 in the original bit depth and eventually split the channels for analysis.  Using the cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH tag works but changes im.shape. What is happening and how can I avoid this behavior? This is being done in Colab.

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread(image.tiff)

print(im.dtype)
print(im.shape)

im = cv2.imread(image.tiff, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

print(im.dtype)
print(im.shape)
```

The output:

```
uint8
(957, 641, 3)
uint16
(957, 641)
```

According to various posts this should not happen.  Still not sure why the channels are being lost.

Comment: By default, cv2.imread forces the image to become 8 bit 3 channel BGR (so that diffrrent images can be used by the same processing). By using the flags you can keep the original image properties, which seems to be 1 channel 16 bit in your case.

Comment: It might be interesting for other users if you shared your TIFF (using Dropbox or Google Drive). It would certainly be instructive if you ran `exiftool YOURIMAGE.TIF` and clicked [edit] and pasted the output into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read .tif image in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102018/how-to-read-tif-image-in-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this issue can be totally avoided using the following different tag.

```
im = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

This preserves the dtype and shape.

Comment: what dtype and shape do you get with this flag?