# Why does matplotlib.image.imread(img) gives very high pixel value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

Why does `matplotlib.image.imread(img)` give such high pixel values? In my understanding, pixel values are between 0 and 255 for grey scaled images. However, when using this to load an image, the pixel values were as high as 600. Is this normal? How do I turn it into a normal grey scaled picture matrix (with pixel value between 0 to 255)? I am using python 3.8 in Windows 10.

Comment: It totally depends on the image you read in. Since there is zero information on it...

Comment: Different image formats use different bit-depth for the pixel values.  Many of the standard image formats can use flexible bit depths.  If you can tell us what format image you are using, we may be able to provide more information.

Comment: I used images on 10 bits or more, where 600 is not that high... Once you know the max possible/real value, it's easy to apply a factor on all values to bring them back in the 8 bit range.

Comment: The image is .tif file. I am new to this kind of work, please forgive me if that is not the kind of format you are talking about.

Comment: @B.Go  Sorry forgot to At you guys

Comment: "Unlike JPEG, TIFF files can have a bit depth of either 16-bits per channel or 8-bits per channel" => I guess you got a 16 bit image! = dividing all the values by 256 would work

Comment: This post talks about handling tif images with more than 8 bit per channel:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591694/how-to-display-16-bit-4096-intensity-image-in-python-opencv